Export data locked away in internal storage
I have used a specific app for more than three years (writing down my dreams and updating a sleep statistic). Now this app is all of a sudden gone from the Play store, and the developer is unreachable. I've always known that it is problematic that this app doesn't have an export feature or anything (like many others), but without having specific Android knowledge, I always thought: It's on my device, I will be able to find and extract it somehow. Well, I found out that the app stored the data in a SQLite database in the internal data folder, i.e. in /data/data/<package_name>/.
I am runnning Android 13 and rooting is of course not an option as this will wipe the phone data, as I understand.
I tried accessing the files via adb from my Linux laptop but I cannot cd into it, "permission denied". I also read that these data are encrypted.
Is there any way to access these data (from another device, if needed?)
